# Flexbox with 33.3% width getting whitespace

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a setup for a portfolio that should display all items touching and together, this works fine when the screen is smaller but if its too big it will add white space as seen here:

[image]

I have looked for what could be causing this in devtools with no success, when the screen is slightly smaller (and the scale will follow correctly) it works fine

[image]

This is the section with in HTML:

```
<section class="p-0" id="portfolio">
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
        <div class="row no-gutters popup-gallery">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a class="portfolio-box" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/lights.jpg">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/lights.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Category
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Project Name
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And here is the CSS it loads, and ive looked through and cant see any reason for it to not be full width, maybe wordpress is causing this? I am using this with wordpress.

As you can see pictured, at 900px+ it should be 33.3
[image]

Here is the CSS:

```
.portfolio-box {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    max-width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(240, 95, 64, 0.9);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category,
.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.portfolio-box:hover .portfolio-box-caption {
    opacity: 1;
}
.portfolio-box img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.portfolio-box:focus {
    outline: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ermm really not sure why this became an issue (Not as knowledgeable at CSS as id like to be just yet) but it seems if I both remove the max-width in

> .portfolio-box

and then add this:

> .portfolio-box .img-fluid {
>       min-width: 100%; }

It works just fine, I guess the image didnt want to scale too high, but it looked weird and devtools didnt confused me

Comment: Indeed! Aspect ratio seems to be your problem. To get around this you can make the divs fixed dimensions and use a background image with 


    `background-size:cover`

If you're not worried about IE support you can also use object-fit on your images! https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Edge support should be coming in the near future

Comment: Yeah, i mean im not a css wiz but majority of the time i can just devtool grind it out and get a solution, thankfully i eventually got here too but i was stumped for abit